# U-Boot version extraction for comparision

Tags: regex, linux, bash, embedded-linux, busybox

I am trying to extract U-Boot version from its binary for comparison,
consider that exact string what I want to search is as follow,

```
U-Boot 2013.07.010 (Mar 21 2016 - 12:07:48)
```

so I wrote command with regex as follows,

```
strings uboot | grep "U-Boot \([0-9]\{4\}.[0-9]\{2\}.[0-9]\{3\}\ ([a-z]\{3\} [0-9]\{2\} [0-9]\{4\} - [0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\})\)"
```

However I don't see any output for that above command,

I could make below command work which extracts version only by comparing versions and not looking for date in the string

```
strings uboot | grep "U-Boot \([0-9]\{4\}.[0-9]\{2\}.[0-9]\{3\}\)"
```

Could someone correct/suggest what am I doing wrong in first command?
Is there a better way of doing the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex in 1st command is broken, you need to escape few chars like the dot for a proper match, also for matching the month i.e `Mar` you need `[A-Za-z]{3}` but you have specified only `[a-z]{3}`

Also you can use the `-o` switch to just print out the matched part. From the man page of `grep`:

> -o, --only-matching
>                 Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

To extract just the version use anyone of these:

```
$ grep -oP "(?<=^U\-Boot\s)[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" <<< "U-Boot 2013.07.010 (Mar 21 2016 - 12:07:48)"
2013.07.010
$ grep -oP "(?<=^U\-Boot\s)[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}" <<< "U-Boot 2013.07.010 (Mar 21 2016 - 12:07:48)"
2013.07.010
$ egrep -o "\b[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}\b" <<< "U-Boot 2013.07.010 (Mar 21 2016 - 12:07:48)"
2013.07.010
$ egrep -o "\b[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\b" <<< "U-Boot 2013.07.010 (Mar 21 2016 - 12:07:48)"
2013.07.010
$
```

Comment: Thank you very much, `Mar` was the problem but dot works fine without escape sequence.

Comment: However I didn't understand grep, you are not matching date there, that's just better option from command two right ?

Comment: Yes dot would work fine because a single dot in regex is a metachar matching any char including literal dot itself, i said to escape it for sending out better intention to the reader

Comment: Oh I see, I understand what you say.

Comment: @AnkurTank You need to match the whole string or just extract out the version part? Is your problem solved?

Comment: I want whole string to be matched in regex, I could solve by adding `[A-Za-z]` for matching `Mar` but I was checking second answer of yours.